# PHP: Regular expression for span tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

That is my code:

```
preg_match('/\<span id\="([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+?)\"\>([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+?)\<\/span\>/', '<span id="1">test</span> <span id="2">test1</span>', $match);

    var_dump($match);
```

But why in $match array have only id=1 and test?

Comment: I literally don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Regex shouldn't be used with HTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I need to get spans id and spans values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg-match-all).